# How to add a new project to an existing git repository (VS15)?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I have a git repo for my project, but I'm experimenting with going a different direction. I have created a new project and want to add it to the same repository, but under a different folder (or some way to distinguish it). I want to leave my old project in tact. I cannot create a new repo due to company permissions.

How do I push a new project to an existing git repo?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Is there a way to do it through the Visual Studio Team Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You add it the same way you'd add anything else to a Git repo. It's all just files. Create the project, run `git add`, `git commit`, and `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

You could not create a new repo due to company permissions. Not sure if the new repo is a local repo or a remote repo.

If it's a remote repo, the easiest way is adding a new local repo to put the new created project.

If it's a local repo,  since the folder is out of your original repo. You have to copy the project files under the git repo folder. Then you could be able to push it to remote side.

Comment: It's not able to do it in Visual Studio Team Explorer. You could create a test, add the new project in local git repo branch by selecting add exist project. The repo can't detect the changes and you will not able to commit it to your local repo neither nor push to remote repo.